# DigitalOcean Console Server Disconnected

Tags: reactjs, nginx, web, server, digital-ocean

I'm trying to access the droplet using the console on the digitalocean website and I keep getting the error shown on the image below.

[Digital Ocean error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YKCN.png)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you should really just contact support@DigitalOcean.com, their response are usually very timely.

Comment: I already created a ticket (2h ago)

Comment: this is a DigitalOcean problem, there's also no error shown in your screenshot. You should either spin up a new droplet or try a new browser to see if same problem occur, else you have to wait for DO.